# Using SolidJS with Parcel & @suid/material build fails

Tags: typescript, parceljs, solid-js

I've tried to use the `SolidJS`+`Parcel`+`TypeScript` template starter project from here:
https://github.com/TiagoCavalcante/solidts-parcel

And once I import any element from `@suid/material`, such as `Button`, build fails.

Here's how to reproduce:

1. Checkout project template from the about URL.
2. `npm i --save @suid/material`
3. Put the following in `index.tsx`:

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import SuidButton from '@suid/material/Button'

function App() {
    return <>
    <SuidButton>Testing</SuidButton>
    </>;
}

render(App, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

You will get an error output:

```
 Build failed.

@parcel/transformer-js: Expected ',', got 'ownerState'

  C:\Users\alona\dev\parcel\node_modules\@suid\material\Button\Button.jsx:307:25
    306 |     const contextProps = useContext(ButtonGroupContext);
  > 307 | Root ownerState={allProps} className={clsx(classes.root, otherProps.className, contextProps.className)} disabled={props.disabled} focusRipp
  >     |      ^^^^^^^^^^
    308 |       <Show when={!!props.startIcon}>
    309 |         <ButtonStartIcon className={classes.startIcon} ownerState={allProps}>
```

My question is, how can I make it play well with `@suid/material`?
it works fine when using `ViteJS` instead of `Parcel`

This issue seems related:
https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/6176
I asked on their discord, and apparently `Parcel` doesn't really support non-standard JS syntax in node_modules (like Typescript or JSX).

This means, that `@suid/material` cannot be used with `Parcel`, as well as others such as `https://github.com/LXSMNSYC/solid-headless`

Comment: For posterity: the official way to build Solid.js projects is with `vite`. There are also examples of doing it with `rollup` or `webpack` and I've had success with both of those, but in my case I always ended up switching to `vite`. But if you are trying to use Parcel you might want to check out this discussion: https://github.com/solidjs/solid/discussions/884

Comment: @m_floer I'm aware of that, was experimenting with Parcel :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no officially supported parcel template but you don't need one.

Here is a basic setup that uses typescript and supports Hot Module Replacement. I did not tested for `@suid/material` but with it should work after you add necessary dependencies.

1. Install `babel-preset-solid` and `@babel/core`.

Parcel automatically picks up babel configuration but it is best to stick to the json based configuration. There is no need for `babel-transform-runtime` and `preset-env` since parcel provides its own alternatives:

> Parcel supports both project wide config files such as babel.config.json, as well as file relative configs such as .babelrc.
>
> Note: JavaScript Babel configs (e.g. babel.config.js) should be avoided. These cause Parcel’s caching to be less effective, which means all of your JS files will be recompiled each time you restart Parcel.
> https://parceljs.org/languages/javascript/#babel

2. Create a .babelrc file with the following content:

```json
{
  "presets": ["solid"]
}
```

3. Add typescript file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxImportSource": "solid-js",
    "noEmit": true
  }
}
```

4. Add hot module replacement (HMR) support if you like. This is a very crude way to add HRM and it loads module as expected but unfortanetly does not preserve the state:

```
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';
import { App } from './App';
const dispose = render(() => <App />, document.body);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
  module.hot.dispose(dispose);
}
```

One minor issue I know of is ParcelJS doesn't support conditional exports yet, which makes ParcelJS load the production build of SolidJS instead of its development build. https://github.com/solidjs/solid-refresh#other-dev-servers

This is not a shortcoming on Parcel's part but an issue due to NodeJS's arbitrary solutions to some common compatibility problems, which can be solved with a plugin.

You can check the link for contents and file structures: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75641238/7134134